# QT. Проблемы с масштабированием виджетов

Tags: qt, масштабирование, qwidget

При создании первого QtWidget-приложения столкнулся с тем, что в исполняемом файле(белое окно) размер элементов (кнопок, текстов) отображается некорректно: не так, как в файле mainwindow.ui . Подскажите, как решить проблему, возникшую уже в самом начале?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Правильное решение: добавить layout'ы и всё сверстать ими, а не вручную позиционировать на форме...

Для того что бы фиксировать начальные размеры главного окна надо внести какую-нибудь правку в геометрию вручную, в редакторе свойств.

Почему не сохраняется геометрия кнопки — не скажу...